# I am getting error using ORDERBY in Sub Query (The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-order-by

The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

I am using join to get result from three tables. Now in the result I am getting multiple record of RMA_ID but I want only the latest record on the basis of TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS.

I am getting this error in the query. Kindly help me out.

```
SELECT RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID,
       PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
       PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_FAILURE_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_COMPLAINT,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS,
       (select TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS from TBL_RMA_SHIPPING where TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID=RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID order by TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.UPDATE_STATUS_DATE),
       RMA_ENQUIRY.[USER_ID],
       TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_DETAILS
  FROM RMA_ENQUIRY 
       LEFT JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID 
       LEFT JOIN PART_SERIAL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
       LEFT JOIN TBL_RMA_SHIPPING ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID=TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID
                  WHERE RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS='A' AND RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS=1
                  ORDER BY RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE DESC
```

Comment: You have such nice joins setup...and then throw this bit into the select statement :  "(select TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS from TBL_RMA_SHIPPING where TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID=RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID order by TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.UPDATE_STATUS_DATE),
      "    change that to a join and call the field properly...it'll eliminate this error and a bunch of confusion, probably make it all faster too.  Ordering by a subquery in a select statement makes no logical sense

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL server and not mySQL as top and For XML are referenced.  Why do you need to do a sub query in the select if you're joining to the table is the left join not returning rows and you must have a value?  if so are you sure your join is on the right columns?  fi so you need to alter the query so it returns one and onyl one record/column based on the related data for that line.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID,
       PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
       PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_FAILURE_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_COMPLAINT,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS,
       TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS, --This doesn't work why?  you only want the max? then...
       --(select TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS from TBL_RMA_SHIPPING where TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID=RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID order by TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.UPDATE_STATUS_DATE),
       RMA_ENQUIRY.[USER_ID],
       TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_DETAILS
  FROM RMA_ENQUIRY 
       LEFT JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID 
       LEFT JOIN PART_SERIAL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
       LEFT JOIN TBL_RMA_SHIPPING ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID=TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID
                  WHERE RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS='A' AND RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS=1
                  ORDER BY RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE DESC
```

if you just want max...

```
SELECT RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID,
       PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
       PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_FAILURE_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_COMPLAINT,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS,
       max(TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS), 
       RMA_ENQUIRY.[USER_ID],
       TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_DETAILS
  FROM RMA_ENQUIRY 
       LEFT JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID 
       LEFT JOIN PART_SERIAL 
                  ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
       LEFT JOIN TBL_RMA_SHIPPING ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID=TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_RMAID
                  WHERE RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS='A' AND RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS=1

GROUP BY RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID,
       PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
       PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_FAILURE_TYPE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_COMPLAINT,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS,
       RMA_ENQUIRY.[USER_ID],
       TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_DETAILS
       ORDER BY RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Actually, the RMA_ENQUIRY table contains all the information about the enquiry which can be identified with RMA_ID And TBL_RMA_SHIPPING table contain the shipping details of Enquiry whose shipping status is '1' in RMA_ENQUIRY Table. I am updating enquiry status (Pending, dispatched, inprocess etc...) of single RMA_ID multiple times and fetching the same Status in my query.

Now the problem is that I am getting multiple records (Shipping status) of RMA_ID, but I want only latest Status in the result not every result.

Answer (score 0):

When using a sub-query in the SELECT clause you can only return 1 value.  Using Top 1 will assure a single value is returns.  Without it the query optimizer assumes multiple values will be returned, which is why your ordering data in the first place.

If sub-query is used in the FROM clause, order will not matter as it will be joined based on the ON conditions.  TOP in this case can be used to limit the result set based on your business requirements.  However, there are workarounds to get ordered data to improve JOIN performance using the TOP clause.  When using sub-queries in the FROM clause multiple records are allowed.

Comment: Actually, the RMA_ENQUIRY table contains all the information about the enquiry which can be identified with RMA_ID And TBL_RMA_SHIPPING table contain the shipping details of Enquiry whose shipping status is '1' in RMA_ENQUIRY Table. I am updating enquiry status (Pending, dispatched, inprocess etc...) of single RMA_ID multiple times and fetching the same Status in my query.

Now the problem is that I am getting multiple records (Shipping status) of RMA_ID, but I want only latest Status in the result not every result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error described in your original post is because like it says, in the sub-select in your main select, you cannot have an ORDER BY there. xQbert's solution will get you only the records with that max value.  For example if you have a table movie_view_history like this:

```
|movie_id|view_date|
--------------------
|  1     |1/1/2014 |
|  1     |1/2/2014 |
|  2     |2/1/2014 |
|  2     |2/2/2014 |
```

xQbert's solution will return:

```
select movie_id, MAX(view_date)
from movie_view_history
group by movie_id

|movie_id|view_date|
--------------------
|  1     |1/2/2014 |
|  2     |2/2/2014 |
```

However, if you want to return the following (who knows, maybe you have a business reason for this):

```
select 
    movie_id,
    (select max(view_date)
     from movie_view_history as [A]
     where [A].movie_id = [B].movie_id)
from movie_view_history as [B]

|movie_id|view_date|
--------------------
|  1     |1/2/2014 |
|  1     |1/2/2014 |
|  2     |2/2/2014 |
|  2     |2/2/2014 |
```

Then you can use the following:

```
SELECT 
  RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID,
   PART_NUMBER_TBL.PART_NO, 
   PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_NUM,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_TYPE,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_FAILURE_TYPE,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_COMPLAINT,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ADDITIONAL_INFORMATION,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS,
   RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS,
   (select [B].SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS from TBL_RMA_SHIPPING AS [B] where [B].SHIP_RMAID=[A].SHIP_RMAID) AS [SHIP_ADMIN_STATUS],
   RMA_ENQUIRY.[USER_ID],
   [A].SHIP_DETAILS
FROM RMA_ENQUIRY 
   LEFT JOIN PART_NUMBER_TBL 
              ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_PART_NO=PART_NUMBER_TBL.PARTID 
   LEFT JOIN PART_SERIAL 
              ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SERIAL_NO=PART_SERIAL.SERIAL_ID
   LEFT JOIN TBL_RMA_SHIPPING AS [A] ON RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_ID=[A].SHIP_RMAID
WHERE RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_STATUS='A' AND RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_SHIP_STATUS=1
ORDER BY RMA_ENQUIRY.RMA_REC_DATE DESC
```

I like xQbert's solution, but it all depends on what you are trying to accomplish!

Comment: The multi-part identifier "TBL_RMA_SHIPPING.SHIP_DETAILS" could not be bound.  This error is coming if I am running the query.

Comment: Actually, the RMA_ENQUIRY table contains all the information about the enquiry which can be identified with RMA_ID And TBL_RMA_SHIPPING table contain the shipping details of Enquiry whose shipping status is '1' in RMA_ENQUIRY Table. I am updating enquiry status (Pending, dispatched, inprocess etc...) of single RMA_ID multiple times and fetching the same Status in my query.

Now the problem is that I am getting multiple records (Shipping status) of RMA_ID, but I want only latest Status in the result not every result.

Comment: I updated to address your first comment.  If you only want the latest record, then I would go with xQbert's solution (second query in the post)